# want to access the data of $catarray in query

Tags: php

```
SELECT PM.*, promotion_type.type_name, country.country_name, province.province_name, 
  region.region_name, towncity.towncity_name FROM promotion As PM
       join country on PM.country_id=country.id
       join province on PM.province_id=province.id
       join region on PM.region_id=region.id
       join towncity on PM.towncity_id=towncity.id
       join promotion_type on PM.promotion_type=promotion_type.id 
       where PM.category_id in('".$catarray."')";
```

Comment: what is in `$catarray`?

Answer (score 0):

As `$catarray` is used this may help you out -

```
 PM.category_id in('".implode(",", $catarray."'))

$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated;
```

the out put will be -  `lastname,email,phone`